# div onclick doesn't work for some reason

Tags: html, onclick

It's a very simple question and I'm amazed how is this not working for me, somehow this code:

```
<div id="logoutDiv" onClick="php_includes/logout.php"></div>
```

doesn't work, when I press on the div. What's the problem? I know that this is a very basic question, but somehow I've got stuck on it.

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp

Comment: Onclick is for javascript, you could have something like onClick="location.window='php_includes/logout.php'", but still just wrap an <a></a> around it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

onclick is a JavaScript event. What you wrote is not JavaScript.

Maybe:

```
onclick="window.location.href='php_includes/logout.php';"
```

Comment: Thanks,I'll accept your answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 0):

onClick only works with Javascript, not with links. Try this instead:

```
<a href="php_includes/logout.php"><div id="logoutDiv"></div></a>
```

Comment: Logout.php has to be independent of whatever included it for that to work, so logout.php may also need revision.

Comment: Inline elements should not contain block-level elements

Answer (score 0):

Use window.location to call another page. `<div id="myButton" onclick="window.location = 'php_includes/logout.php';">Page 2</div>`